# Is it possible to draw this network using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw networks like network in the figure below.
I can draw similar networks using tokens, nodes and edges but the problem is that I can only connect nodes by edges.

What I need is to **connect tokens inside nodes by edges** like the figure below: (In this example, node R has two tokens. One of them is connected to node A and the other is connected to node B.)

Is it possible to achieve this using Tikz?

[image: network]

Here is what I tried so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm] 
\begin{scope} 
\node [place,tokens=1](0)[label=below:$A$]{}; 
\node [place,tokens=2] (1) [right of=0,label=below:$R$] {} edge (0); 
\node [place,tokens=1] (2) [right of=1,label=below:$B$] {} edge (1); 
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! yes, it is possible to draw this figure :-). what you try so far? please show us this!

Comment: Thanks :)

Here is what I tried so far:


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
    \begin{scope}
    \node [place,tokens=1](0)[label=below:$A$]{};
    \node [place,tokens=2] (1) [right of=0,label=below:$R$] {}
    edge (0);
    \node [place,tokens=1] (2) [right of=1,label=below:$B$] {}
    edge (1);
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of many possible methods:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={fill,circle, minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0,node contents={}},
  circ/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt, node contents={}}
]

\node [dot, name=n1];
\node [dot, name=n2, right=of n1];
\node [dot, name=n3, right=5mm of n2];
\node [dot, name=n4, right=of n3];

\draw (n1) -- (n2) (n3) -- (n4);

\node [circ,fit=(n2)(n3), label={[name=R]below:R}];
\node [circ, left, at=(n1.east), name=A];
\node [circ, right, at=(n4.west), name=B];

\node at (A |- R) {A};
\node at (B |- R) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply using the `arrows.meta` library, the `Circle` tip can be used and customized as you want, e.g, `>={Circle[length=5pt]}, shorten >= -5pt, shorten <= -5pt` will use a `5pt` filled circle and will also lengthen the line by the same amount in both sides. If you want the tip touch the circle from inside, just subtract another `\pgflinewidth` from the above.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Circle[length=5pt]}, shorten >= -5pt-\pgflinewidth, shorten <= -5pt-\pgflinewidth]

\node(a) at (0,0) [draw,circle,minimum size=.5cm]{};
\node(r) at (2,0) [draw,circle,minimum size=1cm]{};
\node(b) at (4,0) [draw,circle,minimum size=.5cm]{};

\node at ([yshift=-2em]a) {A};
\node at ([yshift=-2em]r) {R};
\node at ([yshift=-2em]b) {B};

\draw[<->] (a) -- (r);
\draw[<->] (r) -- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document
```

> [image]